# Hill Titan Pterosaur that breaths fire! How to kill this monster?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

My Fortress has been randomly chosen to be the destiny of the attack of a flying Hill Titan that can throw fire:

> An enourmous hairy pterosaur.
>
> It has four long curving horns and it moves deliberately.
>
> Its mint green hair is unkempt.
>
> Beware its fire!
>
> It is tough, but it is slow to heal and very weak.

It killed half of my fortress in battle, but fortunately lost the ability to fly and the ability to stand up. So I locked it on a bedroom it entered and walled the door, to stop the bloody fight that I was losing to it.

This is not an end for me, because, although it is not a Dragon and so its fire cannot melt Shale Block walls, something could happen in the future, like a Dragon attack, a Dwarf seeking FUN, or a landslide, and let this Pterosaur free to throw fire at everything again. Also, my game is extremely slow since it appeared, and I cannot continue to play at this sluggish speed.

How do I kill it, then? The last time I tried teaming up all my squads and making an attack together, the Hill Titan burnt all my Squads inside their Iron armors. I cannot see how to kill it if my Dwarves cannot stand the fire it throws.

Is there any way to make my Dwarves fire-proof?

[image: Hill Titan Description]

[image: Hill Titan Traits]

[image: Pterosaur final prison]

Comment: "Also, my game is extremely slow since it appeared, and I cannot continue to play at this sluggish speed." I discovered that the fires, and possibly the grass re-growing from the ashes, were the responsibles for the performance drop, as the Pterosaur is still kept as a prisoner, but the game speed returned to normal.

Comment: Send in someone as cannon fodder first (you know, that annoying one always throwing tantrums?). Then while the fire is recharging send in the real soldiers. I managed to kill a similar titan like that, due to a stray hunter accidentally walking past it just as I attacked. This was outdoors though. Or... could try to collapse the roof in its head, drop mining cart on it, drown it etc etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

High-skill shield users can deflect fire breath attacks, even with wooden shields. This works against dragons too! Shields should always be a fundamental part of any military uniform.

If you don't have the shield users to deal with the problem through pitched battle, the next easiest way is to hollow out the area above it (leaving only a thin ceiling), then arrange a cave-in covering the entire area. This is guaranteed to destroy anything beneath it.

```
c___c level 3
_I___ level 2
##__# level 1 (titan trapped here)

c = hatch
I = support
```

A setup like this will do it. Make sure the support is on firm ground, so that the entire target zone is covered by soon-to-be-unsupported floors. The hatches will let your dwarves walk across to build the drop-floor, but won't support it when the support is destroyed. Then link the support to a faraway lever, make sure everyone is evacuated, and set it off!

However, I would not guarantee your titan is as locked up as you think. All titans are level 2 "building destroyers". This doesn't let them destroy walls (nothing can do this), but it does make them capable of bashing down even stone doors, except for artifact doors. Additionally, since it's described as "very weak", it will likely take quite a while for it to bash down a door; it has to use its melee attacks for this, not its fire. So you might want to hurry...

Comment: "This doesn't let them destroy walls (nothing can do this), but it does make them capable of bashing down even stone doors" I feel happy to have ordered the walling of the doors, then. But the dwarves are not building the walls...

Comment: This would be more engineering effort but drowning in water instead of a cavein should work as well. If you drain the water afterwards you can even keep the corpse and butcher it.

Comment: @quarague I'm afraid that the Hill Titan would swim upwards the water stream and start throwing fireballs again. Couldn't this happen?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Some creatures can swim and be fine but I don't think a hill titan can. Not a 100% sure though.

Comment: @quarague I prefer not to risk. The fireballs are very devastating, losing only to Dragonfire in this aspect.

Comment: I really did not pay due attention to the shield. I never guessed it would be able to help with fire breath. I always though it was useful only for meelee attacks. Now there are enough shields for all my squads, and all squad members are required to use shields when on duty. Thank you!

Comment: "arrange a cave-in covering the entire area" Which entire area? Have you seen the screenshot that shows the rooms? The "entire area" would be just the 4 tiles that makes up one room?

Comment: Wherever it's trapped. It looks like you're missing a square of wall in the corner between those four rooms, which the titan can squeeze through, so the whole 5x5 area would have to be covered. Anything that a cave-in lands on is automatically destroyed, no saving throw allowed!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot create a cave-in anymore, because the Titan healead after some years and is able to fly again. I'll need to keep it locked in there.

Comment: Cave-ins still work against flying creatures. You just have to be a little more careful not to punch a hole in the ceiling while you're setting it up. But it's still totally possible.